# Can two people play the Hay Day game on one iPad?

Tags: ipad

Can two people with different Apple IDs play the same game on one iPad? I am already playing a game, and my son would like to play, but he wants his own game, is that possible if he has his own Apple ID or Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

Game Center only allows one sign in at a time, so you could sign out and then sign in another account. Most games also keep a local save file, so this might mix the results, but you would need to ask the developer of each app how it handles a log out of one Game Center account and into another.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you create/use a different game center game, it still brings up the game which was originally started.  There's no way to have two different games going at once.